# Rails test using rspec, shoulda_matcher and factory_bot_rails rturns PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails, shoulda-matchers

I have 2 model: Answer and Book.

Although they are very similar, all tests pass to Answer but 1 test fails for Book

**models/answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question, class_name: "Question", foreign_key: "question_id"

  validates :text, presence: true
  validates :correct, presence: true
  validates :question_id, presence: true
end
```

**models/book.rb**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grade, class_name: "Grade", foreign_key: "grade_id"

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :grade_id, presence: true  
end
```

**spec/factories/answers.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :answer do
    text { Faker::Book.author }
    correct { %i(false, true).sample }
    question
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/books.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book do
    name { Faker::Book.title }
    grade
  end
end
```

**spect/models/answer_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Answer, type: :model do

  describe 'validation' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:text) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:correct) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:question_id) }
    it { should belong_to :question }
  end
end
```

**spect/models/book_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Book, type: :model do

  describe 'validation' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:grade_id) }
    it { should belong_to :grade }
  end
end
```

The message I get in return is:

> 1. Book validation is expected to validate that :name is
>    case-insensitively unique
>    Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
>
>    Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord::ValidateUniquenessOfMatcher::ExistingRecordInvalid:
>    validate_uniqueness_of works by matching a new record against an
>    existing record. If there is no existing record, it will create one
>    using the record you provide.
>
>    ```
>    While doing this, the following error was raised:
>
>      **PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "grade_id" violates not-null constraint**
>      DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, null, null, 2021-12-23 15:03:39.977355, 2021-12-23 15:03:39.977355).
>
>    The best way to fix this is to provide the matcher with a record where
>    any required attributes are filled in with valid values beforehand.
>    ```

I have tried many ways that I came up with or saw in stack/git posts but none seams to work.

Comment: Do you have a factory for grades?

Comment: Yes, I do. I should have posted it to. However y may have found the propper answer. Thanks for care about.

Comment: Side note, your class_name and foreign_key arguments are redundant; they are the defaults. So is the presence check on the foreign key, belongs_to does that. Checking the foreign key in your tests pierces the relationship. Check question and grade, not question_id and grade_id.

Comment: Could I leave jut as
    belongs_to :question
or better 
    belongs_to :question, foreign_key: "question_id"
???

Comment: You've defined the books factory as `factory :book do
    name { Faker::Book.title }
    grade
  end`, it'd be good to know how the grade factory is defined to see why you can not create two records given that definition. Another way to see what happens is to debug an attempt to create two records in a separate `it` block.

Comment: @wagnerbraga `belongs_to : question`. It will figure out the foreign key and class from the name: question_id and Question. Rails refers to this as [Convention Over Configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record).

Answer (score 2):

When trying test uniqueness in a model that has a reference you need to provide one to be compare first.

For doing so you should specify the subject:

```
 describe 'validation' do
    subject{ 
    }
```

After that you can call FactoryBot to build the one to be compere to:

```
FactoryBot.build(:book)
```

Final snipet:

```
  describe 'validation' do
    subject{ 
     FactoryBot.build(:book)
    }
```

Mr. [Schwern][1] Enhanced the code a little better:

```
describe 'validation' do
  subject{ build(:book)}
```

Answer (score 2):

This situation is covered in the [validates_uniqueness_of docs](https://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v5.1.0/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveRecord.html#validate_uniqueness_of-instance_method).

> If there is no existing record, it will create one using the record you provide.

Your spec doesn't say how to create a Book, and it doesn't know that it needs a Grade. You need to tell it, it won't use the factory. Do this by adding a [subject](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/subject) for your one-liners to use.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Book, type: :model do
  subject { build(:book) }

  describe 'validation' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
    it { should belong_to :grade }
  end
end
```

Note that `it { should validate_presence_of(:grade_id) }` is redundant with `it { should belong_to :grade }`. belongs_to already validates presence.

Comment: I've made as per your recomendation and worked just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @wagnerbraga You're welcome. I noticed a subtle issue with your book factory. `name { Faker::Book.title }` might create books with duplicate names and cause random test failures. Use [`unique`](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values) to avoid that. `name { Faker::Book.unique.title }`